# C# encapsulation (get and set)

Tags: c#, oop, encapsulation

I am doing exercises in Head First C# book.

This code is supposed to be about encapsulation.

```
class DinnerParty
{
    private int NumberOfPeople;
         ....

    public void SetPartyOptions(int people, bool fancy) {
        NumberOfPeople = people;
        .....
    }

    public int GetNumberOfPeople() {
        return NumberOfPeople;
    }
}
```

In `form1` class

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DinnerParty dinnerParty;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dinnerParty = new DinnerParty() {NumberOfPeople = 5 };

        ...
```

Is this suppose to work?

Visual Studio is showing me an error. (cannot access due to its protection level)

I am very new at this.

Thanks

Comment: This code will not work, because of `private`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not supposed to work. I can't see the book, so I can't comment on the context. However:

```
public int NumberOfPeopoe {get;set;}
```

Is a reasonable fix.

Comment: No it's not. This means I can now set the NumberOfPeople directly, which I should only be able to do through the method he's providing..

Comment: @Alan the question supplies two conflicting uses; it also presents member assignment. If that is intended to work, we have two options: a public field or a property with public set. Having a `GetNumberOfPeople()` method, for example, is not idiomatic c# (where a property get would seem more typical)

Comment: It was first private int NumberOfPeople;. It worked then. but the book asked me to change it to "Private" and then add the get and set methods. It does not work now.

Comment: Sorry i meant it was first set public int NumberOfPeople.

Comment: @gripmYgrip the first version is a public field; never a good idea (indeed: encapsulation). Have you checked for an errata? Maybe the code sample is fixed there, to call the method? Wrapping in a property (as I've done via the `{get;set;}` is another way of introducing basic encapsulation (giving us the option of adding more checks etc later)

Answer (score 1):

That's becouse `NumberOfPeople` is [`private`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx) means that it can't be accessible from outside the class `DinnerParty`, so you need to make it [`public`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the idea of a "[Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C.23)" by writing something like:

```
class DinnerParty
{
    private int NumberOfPeople;

         ....

    public DinnerParty SetPartyOptions(int people, bool fancy) {
        NumberOfPeople = people;
        .....

        return this; // Return own instance to allow for further accessing.
    }

    public int GetNumberOfPeople() {
        return NumberOfPeople;
    }
}
```

And then call it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DinnerParty dinnerParty;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dinnerParty = new DinnerParty().SetPartyOptions( 5, true );

        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

NumberOfPeople  is a private member and you can not use it out of the class dude

Answer (score 0):

The NumberOfPeople is private, so it will not work. The best solution here is to create public property instead of private field or add constructor and initialize this field there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize a private field outside your scope (class).

Make it a property.

```
public int NumberOfPeople { get; set; }
```

and now, this will work

```
dinnerParty = new DinnerParty() { NumberOfPeople = 5 };
```